# Bootable USB device requirement for ASUS Eee PC 1000HE

Tags: boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, eee-pc, asus-laptop

Does the EEE require a particular USB flash drive capability or property?

I have a Sandisk flash drive that boots correctly on every accessible USB-bootable computer. For some reason the 1000HE BIOS has difficulty seeing the known-good Sandisk flash drive as a boot drive.

Comment: Have you tried witha differe t flash drive? When the machine boots, try pressing ESCto see if it lets you select the drive from a list of available boot devices. Also try F2 or Del to get into the BIOS and manually set USB devices to boot first.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the ESC key did it for me.  It brings up a boot menu and the USB device containing the .iso file will show up and can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled getting USB flash to boot Linux on Eee PC 1005PE. What worked for my flash drive was disabling Boot Booster in Bios.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.